# is there a limit to how much data scipy.interpolate.interp2d can handle? --> wrong results with large vectors

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have been using scipy.interpolate.interp2d to compute the results for a 131x29344 grid.
unfortunately, there seems to be a problem when inserting such large vectors into the interpolated function. The results are not the same as results of the same numbers in smaller vectors.

eg.:

```
# setting up a function 
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5.01, 5.01, 0.25)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx**2+yy**2)
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')
```

now two vectors are defined:

```
vec1 = np.arange(0,1.31,0.01)
vec2 = np.random.rand(29344) #note, if vec 2 is just np.arange(0,29344), there is no problem
vec3 = np.arange(0,29344)
```

now we can test whether the function can handle the data:

```
my_matrix = f(vec1,vec2)
#now the following statement should be true but it is not
f(vec1,vec2[10000]) == my_matrix[10000]
```

but

```
my_matrix2 = f(vec1,vec3)
f(vec1,vec3[10000]) == my_matrix2[10000]
#is true
```

Does anyone know why this problem arises or how it can be solved? Looping through the values would take up too much time.

Comment: Just to add, if the vec2 is divided into smaller parts, the function seems to work, but still it requires a loop to go through the whole vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
The called function sorts the input vectors. Therefore the ordering of the results is not equal to the input data. So basically if we have vec1 = [1,2,3] and vec2 = [5,2,3], f(vec1,vec2) will sort the vectors before giving an output. Therefore, the output will be for f([1,2,3],[2,3,5]) which will lead to a different structure of course.
See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.